# Yii 2 Kartik input validation message is coming while clicking the browse button only

Tags: php, yii2, kartik-v, yii2-validation

```
  <?php     use kartik\file\FileInput;
              use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

              $form = ActiveForm::begin([
             'id' => 'import-pdf',
             'options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
    ]); ?>

        <?=
        $form->field($model, 'file_name')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
            'options' => ['multiple' => false],
            'pluginOptions' => [
                'showPreview' => false,
                'showCaption' => true,
                'showRemove' => true,
                'showUpload' => false,
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
```

```
//file_name is the attribute I'm using it

    public function rules()
   {
       return [
           [['file_name'], 'required'],
           [['status', 'total_pages', 'processed_pages', 'file_type'], 'safe'],
           [['total_pages', 'processed_pages', 'file_type'], 'integer'],
           [['file_name'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'extensions' => 'pdf'],
           [['status'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
       ];
   }
```

File name cannot be blank message is coming while clicking browse button only, It should show the validation message after selecting the file only

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuENh.png

Comment: Can you show the rules method of the model?

Comment: Sure, updated the rules in question now

Comment: The validator tfr field 'Filename' must be 'file':
[['file_name'], 'file'],

Comment: Yeah I tried that also, so again I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to assign to $file_name the uploadedFile instance before the validation?

```
$model->file_name = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file_name');
```

or

```
 $model->file_name = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('nameOfTheField');
```

Comment: I have added this already like below


if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                $model->file_name = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file_name');
       }